# Каким образом можно "обойти" MemoryError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Имеется примитивный алгоритм проверки числа на простоту:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num%6 in [0,2,3,4]: 
        return False
    for i in range(2,int(num**0.5)+1):
        if num%i==0:
            return False
print(is_prime(123456789876543217))
```

Python 3 не выполняет код, возвращая ошибку `MemoryError` и указывая на `range()`. При замене `range()` на `xrange()` и, соответственно, переходе на Python 2 всё прекрасно работает.
Как я понимаю, это связано с тем, что (очень примитивно) `range()` генерирует список из всех значений, который остается в памяти, в то время как `xrange()` использует каждое число только один раз. Каким образом можно обойти эту проблему в Python 3?
P.S.: Проблема оказалась лишь в том, что я запускал код прямо в Sublime Text, а не через консоль

Comment: В моём Python 3 функция отлично работает (не считая неверного ответа для чисел 1, 2, 3) даже при `print(is_prime(12345678987654321700000000000000000000000000000000000000000001))`. Вы точно-точно уверены, что запускаете этот код именно в Python 3?

Comment: @andreymal Проверил, оказалось- я дико тупил и запускал код прямо в sublimetext, в "нормальном" Python 3 всё работает

Comment: ``range()`` во третьем питоне работает так же, как ``xrange()`` в питоне втором. Точнее говоря, ``xrange()`` из второго питона в третьем называется ``range()``.